# How to grab a string from an array

Tags: c, arrays, string

programming in C.

I'm working on a function that uses getline to get input from the user.

if the first word in a string of text is S, it will call a funtion that will save a 2Darray to a document.

the name of the file will be whatever the user types after the S.

So if the user were to type S myfile.txt, the function will save the file as myfile.txt.  I can't figure out how to grab a string from the aray that will be the name of the file.  I don't think my user of the pointers is correct eaither.

```
void copy_to_file(char** board, int num_rows, int num_cols, char* filename){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename.txt, "w");
    int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = (num_rows - 1); i >= 0; --i) {
    fprintf("%d ", i);
    for (j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
    fprintf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf("\n");
    }
    fprintf(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < num_cols; ++i) {
    fprintf("%d ", i);
    }
    fprintf("\n");

    fclose(f);

    }//end coppy to board

    int main(int argc, char** argv)

    {
    char** board
    do
    {   
       printf("Enter your command: ");
       fgets(command, 100, stdin);

    if( command[1] == 's"){

    copy_to_file(char** board, int num_rows, int num_cols, char* filename)

    }

   }while(!(get_valid_input(command)));
```

Comment: `command[1] == 's"`. Does your program even compile? I'm guessing it doesn't. If that is the case then you should ask about that by providing the exact error messages.

Comment: "a function that uses getline". The code shown does not call `getline` anywhere. Please take the time to provide the correct information.

Comment: `fprintf` 1st argument is `FILE *`

Answer (score 1):

sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char commands[512] = "S myfile.txt\n";
    char command, filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];

    sscanf(commands, " %c %[^\n]", &command, filename);
    printf("command:%c, filename:%s\n", command, filename);
    return 0;
}
```